# Find absent dates of employee and one date before & after present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following sample data:

```
--Table 1:
CREATE TABLE tbl_Emp_1
(
    EmpID INT,
    ColDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(1,'2019-11-01');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(2,'2019-11-02');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(3,'2019-11-11');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(4,'2019-11-12');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(9,'2019-11-13');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(6,'2019-11-16');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_1 VALUES(408,'2019-11-25');

--Table 2:
CREATE TABLE tbl_Emp_2
(
    EmpID INT,
    ColDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_2 VALUES(11,'2019-11-02');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_2 VALUES(22,'2019-11-06');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_2 VALUES(22,'2019-11-08');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_2 VALUES(33,'2019-11-10');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_2 VALUES(44,'2019-11-15');

--Table 3:
CREATE TABLE tbl_Emp_3
(
    EmpID INT,
    ColDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_3 VALUES(111,'2019-11-12');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_3 VALUES(222,'2019-11-16');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_3 VALUES(333,'2019-11-17');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_3 VALUES(444,'2019-11-19');
INSERT INTO tbl_Emp_3 VALUES(5,'2019-11-22');
```

--Now I will create View of these tables.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Emp AS
SELECT *,1 AS TableID FROM tbl_Emp_1
UNION ALL
SELECT *,2 AS TableID FROM tbl_Emp_2
UNION ALL
SELECT *,3 AS TableID FROM tbl_Emp_3;
```

**Expected Output**:

```
EmpID   ColDate     
--------------------------------
2       2019-11-02          ---TABLE 1 Starts
NULL    2019-11-03 - 2019-11-10
3       2019-11-11
9       2019-11-13
NULL    2019-11-14 - 2019-11-15
6       2019-11-16
NULL    2019-11-17 - 2019-11-24
408     2019-11-25
11      2019-11-02          ---TABLE 2 Data Starts
NULL    2019-11-03 - 2019-11-05
22      2019-11-06  
NULL    2019-11-07
22      2019-11-08
NULL    2019-11-09
33      2019-11-10
NULL    2019-11-11 - 2019-11-14
44      2019-11-15
111     2019-11-12      ---TABLE 3 Data Starts
NULL    2019-11-13 - 2019-11-15
222     2019-11-16 
333     2019-11-17
NULL    2019-11-18
444     2019-11-19  
NULL    2019-11-20 - 2019-11-21
5       2019-11-22
```

**About the output**: Display absent dates of Employee and display emp data of one date before and after those dates(employee not exists dates).

**My try**:

```
DECLARE @TableID INT,
        @MinDate DATE,
        @MaxDate DATE;
DECLARE Cur_Get_MinMax1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TableID,
       (SELECT MIN(ColDate) FROM vw_Emp WHERE TableID = v1.TableID),
       (SELECT MAX(ColDate) FROM vw_Emp WHERE TableID = v1.TableID)
FROM vw_Emp v1
GROUP BY TableID;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempEmpData') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TempEmpData;

CREATE TABLE #TempEmpData
(
    Dates DATE,
    TableID int
);

OPEN Cur_Get_MinMax1;

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Get_MinMax1 INTO 
@TableID, 
@MinDate,
@MaxDate;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT(@TableID);
    PRINT(@MinDate);
    PRINT(@MaxDate);

    INSERT INTO #TempEmpData 
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate),
            @TableID
    FROM sys.all_objects a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Get_MinMax1 INTO 
    @TableID, 
    @MinDate,
    @MaxDate;

END;
CLOSE Cur_Get_MinMax1;
DEALLOCATE Cur_Get_MinMax1;
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT v.EmpID,t.Dates
FROM #TempEmpData t 
LEFT JOIN vw_Emp v ON v.ColDate = t.Dates AND v.TableID = t.TableID
ORDER BY t.TableID,t.Dates;
```

**Edit**:

Query 2:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT TableID,Dates,EmpID,
            coalesce(stuff((select distinct CAST(MIN(Dates) as varchar(10))+'~'+ CAST(MAX(Dates) as varchar(10)) from #TempEmpData t1 where a.rr = 1 AND t1.Dates=a.Dates for xml path('')),1,0,''),cast(Dates as varchar(10))) Coldate
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  v.EmpID, 
                t.Dates,
                t.TableID,
                RANK() OVER(ORDER BY v.EmpID) rr
        FROM vw_Emp v  
        RIGHT JOIN #TempEmpData t ON v.ColDate = t.Dates  AND v.TableID = t.TableID
        GROUP BY t.TableID,v.EmpID,t.Dates,v.TableID
    ) a
)
SELECT EmpID,ColDate 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY TableID,Dates
```

Comment: It's great you've posted sample data as DDL+DML, but still your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I want to display employee data with it's present and absent dates. If the employee absent more than one days in sequence then it should display `FromDate to ToDate` with `null EmpID`. And also want to display one day before and after present date with `empID`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the point of displaying dates with no employee id. That doesn't tell you which employee is absent... Also, the 3 tables structures should probably be a single table, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Actually there will be no employee id for the absent dates, so we just need to get those dates where there is no data present of any employee. There will be only dates of employee which are present, we need to get all those dates first between `MIN(ColDate)` and `MAX(ColDate)` of every table and find out the missing dates. I apologize if i'm still unable to describe it.

Comment: Sorry but, are you trying to get sandwich information. like absent before and after holiday that will make a sandwich of holidays? is that your desired output?

Comment: @SyedWahhab, No it's not like that, I need to get the result as shown in the expected output. Actually there will be no employee id for the absent dates, so we just need to get those dates where there is no data present of any employee. There will be only dates of employee which are present, we need to get all those dates first between MIN(ColDate) and MAX(ColDate) of every table and find out the missing dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this uses window function `LAG()` and `LEAD()` to find previous and next `ColDate` based on `ColDate` ordering.

The first query returns the before and after row when a discontinued date is encounter. The second query returns the date range of the discontinued date.

```
; with 
tbl_Emp as
(
    select  tbl = 1, EmpID, ColDate from tbl_Emp_1  
    union all
    select  tbl = 2, EmpID, ColDate from tbl_Emp_2  
    union all
    select  tbl = 3, EmpID, ColDate from tbl_Emp_3
),
cte as
(
    select  *,
            prevColDate = LAG(ColDate) over (partition by tbl order by ColDate),
            nextColDate = LEAD(ColDate) over (partition by tbl order by ColDate)
    from    tbl_Emp
)
-- first query
select  c.tbl, 
        c.EmpID, 
        c.ColDate, 
        EndDate     = NULL
from    cte c
where   c.ColDate   <> dateadd(day, +1, prevColDate)
or      c.ColDate   <> dateadd(day, -1, nextColDate)

union all

-- second query
select  c.tbl, 
        EmpID       = NULL,
        ColDate     = dateadd(day, 1, c.ColDate),
        EndDate     = dateadd(day, -1, nextColDate)
from    cte c
where   c.ColDate   <> dateadd(day, -1, nextColDate)

order by tbl, ColDate;
```

Note :  i didn't concatenate the `ColDate` and `EndDate` as what you have shown in your expected result.

Comment: Can we alter this query to get 2,3,4 or n numbers of before and after day. Current query return 1 date before and after data.

Comment: please refer to documentation on `LAG()` and `LEAD()` . Use the `offset` parameter to get the `n` numbers that you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) AS EmpId, DATEADD(day, 1, PreviousDate) AS StartDate, DATEADD(day, -1, ColDate) AS EndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ColDate, LAG(ColDate) OVER(ORDER BY ColDate) AS PreviousDate, LEAD(ColDate) OVER(ORDER BY ColDate) AS NextDate
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColDate FROM dbo.tbl_Emp_1) AS src
    ) AS thedates
    WHERE ColDate <> DATEADD(day, 1, PreviousDate)



    SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) AS EmpId, StartDate, EndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, sd.StartDate) AS StartDate, DATEADD(day, -1, MIN(ed.EndDate)) AS EndDate
        FROM 
        (
            --start dates of missing ranges
            SELECT ColDate AS StartDate
            FROM dbo.tbl_Emp_1 as a
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Emp_1 AS b WHERE b.ColDate = DATEADD(day, 1, a.ColDate))
        ) AS sd
        JOIN
        (
            --end dates of missing ranges
            SELECT ColDate AS EndDate
            FROM dbo.tbl_Emp_1 as a
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Emp_1 AS b WHERE b.ColDate = DATEADD(day, -1, a.ColDate))
        ) AS ed ON sd.StartDate < ed.EndDate
        GROUP BY sd.StartDate
    ) AS emptyperiods
```